# Is truncated taylor series a bound?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Given a function $f(x)$ with truncated Taylor series $T_n(x)$ at point $x = 0$, it's possible to $T_n(x)$ cross $f(x)$ in a point $x \neq 0$? In other words, is the truncated Taylor series always an upper/lower for the original function for each interval $x > 0$ and $x > 0$? There's a known result about it? I know that at least the functions can coincide (for instance, the first Taylor series term of $\cos{(x)}$, at multiples of $2\pi$).

Comment: How about $f(x)=(x-1)^3$? Then $T_1(x)=3x-1$; we have $3x-1>(x-1)^3$ for $x<3$ but $3x-1<(x-1)^3$ for $x>3$. Unless I've misunderstood what you're getting at (which is possible), then that's a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!